# Access Denied when trying to get into a ATA-to-USB HDD

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

I need to get into a HDD that I plugged in my HP 8440 (XP Pro) with a USB-to-IDE cable. When I get in the E:\ drive and then in documents and settings, I can't access %username%'s folder. I get a Access Denied error message.

I've enabled the Simple Sharing and also enable the network share but still get the same message.

I don't see anything relevant to grant me access from the Disk Management so that's why I'm asking here.

Any takers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to 'Take Ownership' of the files on the hard drive, which then grants you the permissions you need to take 'Full Control' of all the files on the hard drive.  This [link](http://www.preyerplanning.com/take-ownership-of-entire-hard-drive-in-windows-7.pdf) shows you how to do it in Windows 7; and while not exactly the same the process is very similar.  I'm sure if you do some more searching you can find the relevant link for a windows xp specific version.

Comment: I was also looking for that but I only have 3 tabs when right clicking on the drive. General, Sharing and customize. I don't even see the Security tab!?

Comment: @r0ca That's because of the simplified sharing, turn that off.